# Nick in 2-2-2-4 SER Aluminum cable

Tags: electrical, wiring

I finally was able to get my 2-2-2-4 SER cable into the LB conduit, then noticed this nick.  I am running it in conduit only from the LB to the bottom of the subpanel, which is about 4 feet above the LB, for protection purposes in my attached garage.  Do I need to rerun a new SER cable?
[image]

Comment: How deep is the nick?  Just outer covering not so much, into the Al wire maybe.

Comment: It looks like just the outer sheathing, there's a paper thin plastic inner sheathing as the next layer after the gray outer sheathing, and that looks still intact.

Comment: I think if just the outer covering, electrical tape should fix.  Unknown if it is allowed for larger gauge cables